# Sum of random variables that are normally distributed and correlated

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, conditional-probability, moment-generating-functions

Suppose that $X$, $Y$ and $W$ are jointly normal random variables, such that $X\sim N(\mu_x,\sigma_x^2)$, $Y\sim N(\mu_y,\sigma_y^2)$ and  $W\sim N(\mu_w,\sigma_w^2)$ where $\sigma_{x,y}\neq 0$ and $\sigma_{x,w}= 0 = \sigma_{w,y}$. Furhtermore, suppose that $S=X+u$, where $X$, $u$ are independently disributed and $u\sim N(0,\sigma_u^2)$. If $(X,Y,W,S)$ are jontly normally distributed, then how can we show that the random variable $Z=X+WY$ conditional on $F=\{S,W\}$, namely $Z|F$ is also a Gaussian normal?

Comment: $(Z,S)$ is jointly normal. It is a well-known fact that conditional distributions formed from components of a joint normal distribution are themselves normal; one proof involves computing the ratio of densities $f_{Z,S}(z,s)/f_S(s)$ explicitly.

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are gaussian it is not necessarily true that $(X,Y)$ is a gaussian vectors. If $X$ and $Y$ are independent it is true. So your affirmation that $(X,Y,S)$ is gaussian is not justified. Observe that $X,Y,S$ are correlated.

Comment: Ok, let me re-edit the problem @RLC

Comment: @angryavian I know that this holds, and i re-edited the problem...

Comment: Can you clarify your notation "$Z \mid F = \{S, W\}$"?

Comment: @angryavian well no, it is. This has to do with the set $F$ that contains $W$...conditional on $F$ the normality holds!

Comment: $F$ is some information set and $F=\{S,W\}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$W$ is independent of $X$ and $Y$ and $S$, so if you are conditioning on it, you can just treat it as a constant throughout the problem. For visual convenience I will denote it as a lower case $w$.

$(Z,S) = (X + wY, X+u)$ is jointly normal since any linear combination $aZ+bS$ is a linear combination of independent normals $X,Y,u$. ([Definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Equivalent_definitions).)

Then it is a well-known fact that the conditional distribution $Z \mid S$ is normal, which you can find on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Conditional_distributions) and [elsewhere online](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30588/deriving-the-conditional-distributions-of-a-multivariate-normal-distribution). One proof approach involves explicitly writing out the density $f_{Z \mid S}(z) = \frac{f_{Z,S}(z,s)}{f_S(s)}$.

---

Response to comments:

If $Z=X+wY$ then $Z \sim N(\mu_z, \sigma_z^2)$ where $\mu_z = \mu_x + w \mu_y$ and $\sigma_z^2 = \sigma_x^2 + w^2 \sigma_y^2 + 2 w \sigma_{x,y})$.
Meanwhile $S = X+u \sim N(\mu_s, \sigma^2_s)$ where $\mu_s = \mu_x$ and $\sigma_s^2 = \sigma_x^2+ \sigma_u^2$. Finally, $\sigma_{z,s} := \text{Cov}(Z, S) = \text{Cov}(X+wY, X+u) = \sigma_x^2 + w \sigma_{x,y}$.

$(Z,S)$ is bivariate normal with the above parameters. At this point you can ignore $X,Y,u$.

Let $V$ be a standard normal random variable independent of all the other random variables.
Then $Z$ has the same distribution as
$$\mu_z + \rho \sigma_z \frac{S-\mu_s}{\sigma_s} + \sigma_z \sqrt{1-\rho^2} \; V$$
where $\rho = \frac{\sigma_{z,s}}{\sigma_z \sigma_s}$ is the correlation between $Z$ and $S$.

\begin{align}
E[e^{tZ} \mid S=s] &= E\left[\exp\left(t \left(\mu_z + \frac{\rho \sigma_z}{\sigma_s} (S-\mu_s) + \sigma_z \sqrt{1-\rho^2} \; V\right)\right) \;\Big|\; S=s\right]
\\
&= e^{t(\mu_z + \frac{\rho \sigma_z}{\sigma_s} (s-\mu_s))}
E[e^{t\sigma_z\sqrt{1-\rho^2} V}]
\\
&= e^{t(\mu_z + \frac{\rho \sigma_z}{\sigma_s} (s-\mu_s))}
e^{t^2 \sigma_z^2 (1-\rho^2)/2}
\end{align}
which is the MGF of a normal distribution with mean
$(\mu_z + \frac{\rho \sigma_z}{\sigma_s} (s-\mu_s))$ and variance $\sigma_z^2 (1-\rho^2)$.

Comment: So to find the $Z|F$ is equivalent as to find $Z|S$, since the r.v. $W \in F$ which means that it is like a constant and it can go out of the mgf and then is just a matter of calculations to proove that it is normal with some mean and variance...

Comment: @HungerLearn Yes just treat $W$ as a constant throughout your calculations. And yes using the MGF or characteristic function is another approach.

Comment: You mean different that what you said? It seems to me the same...but maybe i am wrong...

Comment: So the fact that $X$ and $Y$ are correlated does not play any role?

Comment: @HungerLearn Once you determine the joint distribution $(Z,S)$, you can ignore $X$ and $Y$ and $u$. The correlation of $X$ and $Y$ affects the distribution $(Z,S)$, but does not change the fact that $(Z,S)$ is jointly normal.

Comment: So this is driven by the assumption..ohhh...I see

Comment: Well, by assuming that $U=(X,Y)$ and $a=(1,W)$, then $Z=a^TU$ has a univariate normal distribution, since $(Z,S,W)$ are jointly normally distributed and thus the mgf of the $Z|F$ $$M_Z(t)=E[e^{tZ}]=E\{E[e^{t(a^TU)}|F]\}=E\{e^{ta^T}E[e^{t(U)}|F]\}=E\{e^{ta^T}E[e^{t(X,Y)}|F]\}$$=...

Comment: Well, I don't know if something changes, but  $\sigma_{Z,S} := \text{Cov}(Z, S) = \text{Cov}(X+wY, X+u) = \sigma_x^2+w \sigma_{x,y}$...?

Comment: @HungerLearn Thanks, I've corrected my answer.